# Shell Script: Grep a value from one file and place it in another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 files in 2 different paths. I want to copy the Installed Version from file1 to file2

File 1: **`VersionInfo.Properties`**:

```
Installed Version:13.9.0-9
Previous Version:13.8.0-2
```

File 2: **`Install.sh`**

```
  #!/bin/bash
    --- #some content is there
    ----
   uninstall_and_install_rpm component 13.7.0-3
   -----
    ------
```

**Desired Output:**

File 2: **`Install.sh`**

```
  #!/bin/bash
    --- #some content is there
    ----
   uninstall_and_install_rpm component 13.9.0-9
   -----
    ------
```

Comment: @JP Lew : If you have anything in mind with sed, can you please post it here so that I can try it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        split($0,a,":")
        if (a[1] == "Installed Version") ver = a[2]
        next
    }
    /uninstall_and_install_rpm/ {$NF = ver}
    1
' VersionInfo.Properties Install.sh > Install.sh.new &&
mv Install.sh Install.sh.old &&
mv Install.sh.new Install.sh
```

Comment: That's a shame. Have any details you'd like to share?

Comment: Its just opening the file Install.sh, but doing nothing. I suspect near the line ` /uninstall_and_install_rpm/ {$NF = ver}` as there is one more word also after `uninstall_and_install_rpm component 13.9.0-9`

Comment: My code works according to the sample files you provided. If they don't correspond to reality, you have to edit your question.

Comment: Its opening the file install.sh and updating , but the file is not getting saved. Its just showing me the updated version on screen

Comment: @sravs448: Redirect it to a new file (as you do not want to wipe `Install.sh` until after you have finished reading it), then copy it over.  Redirection add on to the end `> Install_modified.sh`

Comment: @sravs448, *that's* the information you needed to say instead of "its not working". I've updated my answer to accomodate you.